# General mathematical solution to this problem? Code solution given

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, recursion

I'd like to count the number of times a ball will bounce above a certain height. Imagine a ball dropped from a building, and which bounces by a factor of 0,66. How many times it will reach the 2nd floor window at 1.5 meters high from the floor?

I solved it using code, but I thought that maybe there is a general solution to this. Unfortunately my maths courses are far now and I can't quite remember the techniques.

Assumptions are:

- height > window's height
- 1 > bounce rate > 0

Here is the code I used to solve it:

```
def number_of_bounces(height, bounce_rate, window_height):
    """
    Calculates the number of times the ball will pass in front of the window
    """
    if height < window_height:
        return 0
    next_bounce = height * bounce_rate
    if next_bounce < window_height:
        return 1

    passage = 1
    while next_bounce > window_height:
        passage += 2 # Once upward, once downward
        next_bounce = next_bounce * bounce_rate

    return passage
```

Any idea for a general solution to this problem?

Edit : Tests for this problem :
**Initial height** : 2 / **Bounce rate** : 0.5 / **Windows height** : 1 / **Expected result** : 1

**Initial height** : 3 / **Bounce rate** : 0.66 / **Windows height** : 1.5 / **Expected result** : 3

**Initial height** : 30 / **Bounce rate** : 0.66 / **Windows height** : 1.5 / Expected result : 1

**Initial height** : 30 / **Bounce rate** : 0.75 / **Windows height** : 1.5 / **Expected result** : 21

Comment: Assume the height of the building is $R$ and the height that you are interrogating is $S$, and let $~\displaystyle T = \frac{R}{S}.~$  If $n$ is the number of times that the ball exceeds height $S$, then $n$ is the largest integer such that $~\displaystyle R \times (0.66)^n \geq S \implies T \times (0.66)^n \geq 1.~$  Now, take the logarithm of both sides.  So, $n$ is the largest integer such that $~\displaystyle \log(T) + n\log(0.66) \geq 0.~$ Here, it is assumed that $R \geq S$, which implies that $T \geq 1$.  Note that the $\log(0.66)$ is a negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have by energy

$$
\cases{
mgh_0 = \frac 12 m v_0^2\\
mgh_1 = \frac 12 m v_1^2\\
\vdots\\
mgh_k = \frac 12 m v_k^2
}
$$

and also $v_{k+1} = \lambda v_k$ then

$$
h_{k+1} = \lambda^2 h_k,\ \ \ h_0 = H
$$

and solving this recurrence

$$
h_k = H\lambda^{2k}
$$

but $h_k = \frac g2 t_k^2$ or $t_k = \sqrt{\frac 2g H}\lambda^k$ and finally

$$
T_k = t_0+2\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} t_j
$$

$$
T_k = \sqrt{\frac 2g H}+2\sqrt{\frac 2g H}\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda^j = \sqrt{\frac 2g H}+2\lambda\sqrt{\frac 2g H}\left(\frac{1-\lambda^k}{1-\lambda}\right)
$$

NOTE

The "number of seen bounces" can be obtained as follows:

From $h_k = H\lambda^{2k}\ge \bar{h}$ we conclude that

$$
k =  \text{floor}\left[\frac 12\log_{\lambda}\left(\frac{\bar{h}}{H}\right)\right]+1
$$

here $\lambda\lt 1$

or

$$
k =  \text{floor}\left[\frac 12\ln\left(\frac{\bar{h}}{H}\right)/\ln(\lambda)\right]+1
$$

Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing the bouncing process.

```
parms = {H -> 3, h -> 1.5, mu -> 0.66, g -> 9.81};
parms = {H -> 30, h -> 1.5, mu -> 0.66, g -> 9.81};
parms = {H -> 30, h -> 1.5, mu -> 0.75, g -> 9.81};
tmax = 15;
ODE = {y''[t] == -g, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == H, WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -mu y'[t]]} /. parms
soly = NDSolve[ODE, y, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
Plot[{y[t] /. soly, (h /. parms)}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> {0, H /. parms}]
```

[image]

Comment: The OP asks for the number of times the ball is seen through the window... therefore the answer has to be an integer.

Comment: The comment in the code clearly states that it "Calculates the number of times the ball will pass in front of the window"

Comment: @Cesareo I am afraid it is the same for the OP.

Comment: Sorry @Cesareo, indeed I was looking for an integer, as we're counting how many times the ball will be seen at 1.5m high from the floor.

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues Well. I attached a note showing how to obtain the number of times.

Comment: @Cesareo Could you confirm it works for all cases I listed in the edit ? I struggle to input this solution inside desmos calculator.

Comment: Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing graphically the bouncing process. The formulas for number of bouncing where slightly modified.

Comment: If the window is small, at each bounce the ball will be seen twice, least the last one.

Comment: @Cesareo one last question, what does $\overline{h}$ means here ?

Comment: @Benjamin_Mourgues It is the window's height.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the initial height and $h$ the height of the window.

You are looking for the quantity $2n$ such that

$$H 0.66^{n+1}<h\le H 0.66^{n}$$

Taking logarithms, you will have

$$\ln(H)+(n+1) \ln(0.66) < \ln(h) \le \ln(H)+n \ln(0.66)$$

Now form $\frac{\ln(h)-\ln(H)}{\ln(0.66)}$. What can you conclude ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'height of the window'? Is it the height from the floor to the window? By the way, how did you derive this, specifically how did you get two conditions i.e. upper and lower bounds? Also what I was able to get is $h\lt He^{2n}$ ($e=0.66$ here). (Sorry for too many questions)

Comment: Don't be sorry. It's natural on this site to ask questions about questions... Question 1: yes. Question 2: I have a decreasing (geometrical) sequence tending to $0$ ; it is therefore rather natural to "bracket" (the height of the window) using two inequality signs ; the advantage is that it makes things simpler to describe, that's all ; you can work as you indicate by a single inequality (take care : the exponent is $n$, not $2n$) but in this case you have to specify "the first n such that..." ; whereas, with the bracketing, you just say "find the value of $n$ such that..."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check why I got $2n$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @ACB Indeed, each new bounce generates 2 "views" of the ball (one in the ascending phase, one in the descending phase).

Answer (score 0):

The ball is dropped with null velocity at $t=0, z=h$.

The ball dynamics is given by
$$
\left \lbrace
\begin{array}{ccl}
v_z &=& - gt \\
z &=& -\frac12 gt^2 +h
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Simple computations show that the velocity at impact time
$t_1=\sqrt{2h/g}$ is
$
v_1^-=-\sqrt{2gh}
$.

The velocity just after bounce is
$v_1^+ = -\eta v_1^-$.

We know that for an object sent from the ground at positive vertical velocity $v$
the maximum height being reached is
$h_\mathrm{max}={v^2}/{2g}$.

Call $v_n$ the velocity at $n$th bounce
It holds
$v_n^+ = \eta^n \sqrt{2gh}$
which yields the maximum height of $\eta^{2n}\cdot h$

Let $h=30$ $\eta=0.75$, we have
$0.75^{2*5}\cdot 30 = 1.68$ and
$0.75^{2*6}\cdot 30 = 0.95$
This gives 10+1=11 crossings as shown in the Mathematica plot above. So the answer must be 11 and not 21 ?